# Wordpress - cannot change username or password in docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose

If I use this inside docker-compose, it works fine:

```
db_node_domain:
 image: mysql:5.7
 volumes:
   - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mystrongpassword
   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
 container_name: wp_db
 networks:
   - "proxy-tier"

wordpress:
 depends_on:
   - db_node_domain
 image: wordpress:latest
 ports:
   - "8080:80"
 expose:
   - "8080"
 restart: always
 environment:
   VIRTUAL_HOST: blog.mydomain.com
   LETSENCRYPT_HOST: blog.mydomain.com
   LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: foo@mydomain.com
   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_node_domain:3306
   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
 container_name: wordpress
 networks:
   - "proxy-tier"
```

I want to use different username and stronger passwords for MYSQL_USER and WORDPRESS_DB_USER but if I make any changes at all in them I get 502 Bad Gateway from nginx. Can I not change these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you have already **built** the database.
When you have run the `docker-compose up` for the fist time, these values have been set:

```
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mystrongpassword
   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

and this part:

```
 volumes:
   - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

means it is a **persistence data** and after stopping the container, for the next run, the data will be available and new ones will not be set. So you have two options:

- new build

  1. remove the data (or maybe image)
  2. modify `docker-compose.yml` file with new password
  3. running `docker-compose` again
- manually change the password, etc

  1. run the database container
  2. login to the container e.g `docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash`
  3. change the password, etc
  4. logout and **commit** this new change

and it is obvious that **new build** is simpler and better option to do.

Comment: That sorted it, thank you. I'm still a newbie to Docker and didn't think about the previous data persisting :)

Comment: @mharran no problem. This `docker-compose.yml` is just for test. We have a better and much flexible `docker-compose.yml` with **WordPress** if you needed it , let me know

Comment: This was insightful